# How to handle duplicate numbers and two or more digit numbers in an array using binary search?

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary, duplicates

I have written a binary search algorithm it works fine but it does not work properly when there are duplicates or for number two or more digit numbers in the array it returns value not found in the array. What can I do to fix this, will I need to search the array for any duplicates to handle the duplicates?
or can I stop the random number generator from generating duplicates?

Here is the code:

```
public class BinarySearch {

    static int RandomNum;
    static int NumSize;
    static int[] arr;
    static int rangeOfNum;
    static int LookFor;
    static Random numGen = new Random();
    static Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the data set");
        NumSize = Input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the range of the random numbers");
        rangeOfNum = Input.nextInt();
        arr = new int[NumSize];
        for (int i = 0; i <= NumSize-1; i++) {
            RandomNum = numGen.nextInt(rangeOfNum);
            arr[i] = RandomNum; 
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.println("Number is: " + arr[i]);
        System.out.println("Enter number you want to search for: ");
        LookFor = Input.nextInt();
        binarySearch(arr[0], arr.length-1, LookFor, arr);
    }
    //Binary Search Algorithm
    public static int binarySearch(int LowIndex, int HighIndex, int Target, int[] array) {  
        if (LowIndex <= HighIndex) {
            int MidIndex = (LowIndex + HighIndex)/2;
            if (array[MidIndex] == Target){
                System.out.println("Found target value at index " + MidIndex);
                return Target;}
                else if (array[MidIndex] > Target)
                    return binarySearch(LowIndex, MidIndex-1, Target, array);
                    else 
                        return binarySearch(MidIndex+1, HighIndex, Target, array);
        }
        System.out.println("target value not found");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The very first time you call `binarySearch` you call it as follows:

```
binarySearch(arr[0], arr.length-1, LookFor, arr);
```

Change it to

```
binarySearch(0, arr.length-1, LookFor, arr);
```

Comment: thanks mate, excuse the ignorance but what is the difference how does the computer read the two?

Comment: The difference is that the first way is telling the binary search to start at the index given to it by arr[0], so if the first int in your array is 6, then LowIndex will initially be 6, which could be a serious problem if your array only has 4 elements. The second way is setting LowIndex to 0, and since arrays are typically 0 index, it's telling the binary search the correct lowest index of your array.

Comment: To add another thing, you also got unlucky that your array was of type int, and your indices are of type int. If you had an array of type double, or some object, then you'd have gotten a compiler error that would have tipped you off.

Comment: Ook thanks. one more thing what would be the best way to check for duplicates?                                                            I would of thought sequentially but would be slow on a large array

Comment: Unless you know beforehand which digits might be duplicated, you need to scan the sorted array all the way through all least once. Alternatively, you can simply not allow duplicates in the array in the first place (i.e. use a binary search to find the element, if not found, then insert. Otherwise, don't insert). I'm sure there are other more complicated solutions involving hash maps and buckets, but this sounds like it is for a class, so I doubt you'll have an array too big to do a linear scan on.